# How to write a function that type guards if object is not iterable, else throws error?

Tags: typescript

## Background

Awkward library type:

```
declare type Extension = {
    extension: Extension;
} | readonly Extension[];
```

Type-guard

```
export function isIterable(x: any): x is Iterable<unknown> {
  return Symbol.iterator in x;
}
```

## What works

Using type-guard

```
const extensions:Extension = getExtensions();
if (!isIterable(extensions)) { // Guard
  throw Error('extensions should be iterable');
}
console.log(...extensions); // Works
```

## Problem

I'm trying to create a *Type-guarding helper function*:

```
import { isIterable } from '../type-guarded/isIterable';

export const throwIfNotIterable = <T,>(value: T) => {
  if (isIterable(value)) {
    return value;
  }

  throw TypeError(
    `Expected to be iterable, instead got ${value} (${typeof value})`
  );
};
```

Note: Inferred type:

```
const throwIfNotIterable: <T>(value: T, name: string) => T & Iterable<unknown>;
```

## Attempts

#### Attempt 1

```
console.log(...throwIfNotIterable(extensions));
```

ERROR:

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Extension'.
```

#### Attempt 2

```
throwIfNotIterable(extensions, 'not iterable');
console.log(...extensions);
```

ERROR:

```
Type 'Extension | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `throwIfNotIterable` an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) (and perhaps change its name to `assertIsIterable` since assertion functions usually start with `assert`):

```typescript
export function assertIsIterable<T>(
    value: T | Iterable<unknown>
): asserts value is Iterable<unknown> {
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (!isIterable(value)) {
        throw TypeError(`Expected to be iterable, instead got ${value} (${typeof value})`);
    }
}

// ...

const extensions: Extension = getExtensions();
assertIsIterable(extensions);
console.log(...extensions); // Works
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQUQB6JAOwGcBLAez3gF4AoeW+AH3gG8a63aQd9iyAuebLkKk8AblZsAvhIbw4UYGQjIBXYWQDaAXXFVOqEjETwAZgFc8YRCPhECASVwwoAIwggAFFn5Q8yAJT8WLYE8I4gzm4gADwWANZ4JADueAB8zDJwiGYw5ADKyAC2LiQQAHRETlCIhrbkWOLSVKCQsAjmltZk8ADmIIiC3CIEHoGqQjxiVHpYBkamFlY2UAQEEYj2DlVR0QAqqR4yAG5QEGYg-Luy4ZHusXgJyWlUYytrRqEnZwh2Ydt38USKXSLDYRBM8A8AEI7DdXO4PF9zv5-Bl2HREAALGDJeC7NAgDAwHEwDwAA2w6CsIGASBI8BcP3+IAANHUCLgFL0SMYACRMJEgSSQ-kodAkCGCyT+Mn+cRSKhNAD0SvgZXV0zAZA58E4E2G-EG6nIFF6-SNkxGcqob3WmzhUQ8eqG2utWsIpRAZQgJB6HnVZWdxoIcvgKvgAHVDHECFQgA)

Comment: @tj, maybe a stupid question: when got spread syntax an operator precedence? i thought, it would have a higher which means something like `[...(falsyValueOrArray || [])]`. now it works without parentheses, like [...falsyValueOrArray || []]`. actually the operator precedence is low as assignment. have i slept all time?

Comment: @NinaScholz - Not a dumb question! Spread syntax *effectively* has very low precedence (only the comma operator is lower): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table (I say "effectively" because it's not an operator, but you know that. :-) ) Basically, the expression (values and actual operators other than comma) is evaluated, then spread is applied to the result. I'm fairly sure this is how it was always defined (well, by the time it actually hit the spec; they probably played around with it when it was being designed).